# restore postgres backup type "geometry" does not exist

Tags: windows, postgresql, backup, postgis

for the last 2 days i m trying to restore my PostgreSQL backup on my windows but get same error! tried googling it but i didnt found any proper solutions !

my windows command :

> psql -h localhost -U username
>   -d dbname -1 -f C:\Users\m\Desktop\backup.sql

Error i get :

> ERROR : type "geometry" does not exist  Line 4 : point geometry(Point,4326)

notice that i have created postgis extension in my db before trying to restore the back up !! what should i do ? backup file is correct because my colleagues used it on their linux os !

using : PostgreSQL 9.6
        postgis 2.3.0-1

i think this picture helps !! 
http://uupload.ir/files/37ro_postgres.png

Comment: Did you install the postgis extension ? `CREATE EXTENSION postgis`. I mean, make sure it is installed in the right database or right schema.

Comment: yes i did ! i also added CREATE EXTENSION postgis line to backup file but doesnt changed the error !

Comment: what happens if you manually fire `CREATE EXTENSION postgis` to the target database?

Comment: @JimJones it creates it with no problem !

Comment: i ve done it now ! results : ERROR:  extension "postgis" already exists

Comment: well, if `psql -h localhost -U username -d dbname -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis"` runs ok, there is no way that `psql -h localhost -U username -d dbname -1 -f C:\Users\m\Desktop\backup.sql` cannot find the extension. Really puzzling.

Comment: @JimJones yes thats the myths ! eventhough i added CREATE EXTENSION postgis in backup file but it doesnt work ! is it windows problem or i need to create other extensions too ?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. Normally just creating the extension does the trick. Check also if it is a permission related issue and double check in which schema the extension is installed. Good luck!

Comment: @JimJones i ve added a link of my cmd picture i think it can give u a hint !

Comment: Is the restore also done in the database `Tickbed`?

Comment: Could it be a `ticbed` vs `Tickbed` issue?